# pie chart problem involving positive values

Tags: r, pie-chart

I am trying to create a pie chart. Here is some data:

```
tst1  tst2 tst34
13.3  2.3  0.0
70.2  4.5  1.2
1.3   5.2  3.3
```

I tried this code:

```
df_pie <- df %>% select("tst1", "tst2", "tst34")
df_pie$tst1 <- as.numeric(df_pie$tst1)
df_pie$tst2 <- as.numeric(df_pie$tst2)
df_pie$tst34 <- as.numeric(df_pie$tst34)
lbls <- c("Stage 1", "Stage 2", "Stage 3")
pie(df_pie, labels = lbls, main="Pie Chart")
```

But, I am getting an error message in R which is below:

```
Error in pie(df, labels = lbls, main = "Percent of Time in Each Sleep Stage") : 
  'x' values must be positive.
```

I have read some articles where people have had this issue before. I have checked that the data are positive and numeric. Can someone please help?

Comment: The `x` in `pie` is `a vector of non-negative numerical quantities. The values in x are displayed as the areas of pie slices.`

Comment: `x` in a pie chart should be a vector, specifically "a vector of non-negative numerical quantities". How do you want to plot that dataframe?

Comment: ohh, I actually now understand. If I wanted to plot the average of each variable, I could just do something like: x <- c(ave_v1, ave_v2, ave_v3) and then replace x with df_pie. Does that sound right to you @Edo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` in `pie` takes only a positive `vector` as input and not a `data.frame`.  According to `?pie`

> x - a vector of non-negative numerical quantities. The values in x are displayed as the areas of pie slices.

Here is an option with `pmap` to loop over each row

```
library(purrr)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

lst1 <- pmap(df_pie, ~ pie(c(...), labels = lbls, 
       main = 'Percent of Time in each Sleep Stage'))
```

-output

[image]

---

If it would be the average of each column, then use `colMeans`

```
pie(colMeans(df_pie), labels = lbls, 
           main = 'Percent of Time in each Sleep Stage')
```

-output

[image]

---

Or with `apply`

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
lst1 <- apply(df_pie, 1, function(x) pie(x, labels = lbls, 
         main = 'Percent of Time in each Sleep Stage'))
```

#### data

```
df_pie <- structure(list(tst1 = c(13.3, 70.2, 1.3), tst2 = c(2.3, 4.5, 
5.2), tst34 = c(0, 1.2, 3.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun! Can you explain why there are 3 different pie charts outputted as opposed to only 1?

Comment: @D.Fowler The first one is looping over the rows and there are 3 rows in the data you showed.  Based on your comments, you wanted the average of each column.  So, the second code block will help you

Comment: Thank you @akrun. This is incredibly helpful. In R, my pie chart is appearing very small. Do you off hand know how to make it look larger (i.e., like yours)?

Comment: @D.Fowler could be that you used `par`.  Try it on a fresh session or change the `par(mfrow = c(1, 1))`